# Magento 2.2.2 Unable to clear session lock record in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22

Tags: magento2, session, memcached

Environment:

- Magento 2.2.2
- Memcached:1.4.35

Overnight I find myself unable to access the admin area of my Magento installation. No changes were made to the environment. No changes to env.php.

Output when accessing admin area:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: SessionHandler::read(): 
Unable to clear session lock record in 
      /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22
```

Nothing in logs (nginx or magento)

Comment: I also get the same issue in Magento 2.2.7. Please provide the solution if you resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5319. This may resolve your issue.